# How can I up the quarry chunk loading limit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

When I try and place a quarry with a large area I get the following:

```
Quarry size is outside the chunk loading bounds or too small 251 (25)
[BUILDCRAFT]the quarry at 28 68 284 will keep 2 chunks loaded
```

And instead of following the markers, it places with the default size. The limit seems to be 2 chunks, which is extremely restrictive (I can't place a quarry over the boundary between 4 chunks for example).

Is there a way (preferably in-game) of modifying the amount of chunks a quarry can keep loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what that message means or why it appears, but I have a strong suspicion that it's a bug. For me, that message just goes away if I keep trying. Currently, Land Marks just generally have trouble connecting, don't work properly, or crash the server. I don't know what's up with that.

What usually works for me:

1. Place 3 Land Marks to denote the rectangle you want. Do not activate them.
2. Right click the one in the middle (i.e. the one that has 2 adjacent Land Marks). It should form a red rectangle.
3. Place the Quarry *directly in front* of the Land Mark that you just clicked.

If they didn't connect in step 2, try again with 4 Land Marks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Since I have a slow computer I put render distance on tiny. This caused chunks to not load. Since they couldn't load I couldn't place the quarry with the landmark size. I increased the render distance to suit the size of the quarry and it worked once i walked to all the corners of the quarry size. You can just return render distance to Tiny once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For people with this problem, You need to right click the Markers before putting down the quarry. You can just use 3 markers.